# Is it possible to create method which work on any sequence

Tags: python, monkeypatching, duck-typing

I'm just curious is it possible to create function in Python which work on any sequence. For example:

```
>>> def head(self):
>>>     return self[0]
>>>
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.head()
1
>>> xrange(10).head()
0
```

Comment: Why not just write `head(seq)` instead of `seq.head()`?

Comment: @delnan I wanted to know if it possible to use method syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extend the built-in types, no.

You can only *subclass* them, but that only helps if you have full control over the creating and use.

Comment: @Martin but how do I call this function. I've tried code above and got error `'list' object has no attribute 'head'`. I can call it like `head(a)`, but I want to call it like method of list.

Comment: @RomanPekar: I misread your question at first; you cannot extend built-in types.

Comment: yes, thanks Martin, I'll wait a bit for other answers and then accept yours if somebody not comes up with some nice workaround